# How to add temporary attributes to Ruby on Rails model during importation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, roo-gem

I use the roo gem to import data from xlsx files.
But in some cases, column available in the xlsx file will not match the target model. Some columns need concatenation or look-up ... there are more columns in the file than in the target model.
Here is my code:

```
  def load_imported_skills
    #puts open_spreadsheet.nil?
    spreadsheet = self.open_spreadsheet(file)
    header = spreadsheet.row(1)
    (2..spreadsheet.last_row).map do |i|
      row = Hash[[header, spreadsheet.row(i)].transpose]
      import = Skill.find_by_id(row["id"]) || Skill.new
      import.attributes = row.to_hash
      puts "test"
      puts import.attributes
      import
    end
  end
```

How can I temporary add virtual attributes to support actuel imput file structure and do some calculation before saving the processed record?

Thanks for help!

Comment: Use `attr_accessor` in your `Skill` model.

Comment: I would recommend creating a new class to handle this and then create/update the `Skill` after all the work has been done